# Using Websphere Shared Library..Issue: Unable to locate tag library for uri http://struts.apache.org/tags-html why?

Tags: jsp, web.xml, taglib, struts-1, websphere-7

I developed web application using struts1.3.8 and spring2.5, I deployed war file in Websphere7 without jars. I kept the jars in the shared library. when i run the application it is throwing the following error.

```
com.ibm.ws.jsp.JspCoreException: JSPG0047E: Unable to locate tag library for uri http://struts.apache.org/tags-html  
at com.ibm.ws.jsp.translator.visitor.tagfiledep.TagFileDependencyVisitor.visitCustomTagStart(TagFileDependencyVisitor.java:76)  
at com.ibm.ws.jsp.translator.visitor.JspVisitor.processJspElement(JspVisitor.java:366)
at com.ibm.ws.jsp.translator.visitor.JspVisitor.processChildren(JspVisitor.java:419)    at
 com.ibm.ws.jsp.translator.visitor.JspVisitor.processJspElement(JspVisitor.java:234)    
at com.ibm.ws.jsp.translator.visitor.JspVisitor.visit(JspVisitor.java:216)
```

I googled and i came to know that in web.xml we have to do the configuration.
so what kind of configuration i have to do???
Any Idea???
Thanks in Advance.
Laxman Chowdary

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short, don't put those JARs in the shared library; put them into WEB-INF/lib.

Comment: When i put all the jars in the WEB-INF/lib, the application size is huge.. it's 25MB.. So while deploying takes time and some times getting failed also.. So to overcome that i have choosen this way.. Any other alternative????

Comment: That's Java EE for you. And for Java EE, that's not huge. I've had larger applications run on WebSphere with no problems. Trust me, class loader issues are far harder to manage than slow deploy times.